# Change scaling in the graph editor

Tags: graph-editor, 3d-cursor, scale

So I want to scale these points from the 2D Cursor,

[image]

Like in the 3D view you can change [image] to [image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found it, in the graph editor you change this [image] to this [image] at the bottom of the graph editor.